# Scrapy using CSS to extract data and excel export everything into one cell

Tags: python, excel, csv, scrapy

**Here is the spider**

```py
import scrapy
import re

from ..items import HomedepotSpiderItem



class HomedepotcrawlSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'homeDepotCrawl'
    allowed_domains = ['homedepot.com']
    start_urls = ['https://www.homedepot.com/b/ZLINE-Kitchen-and-Bath/N-5yc1vZhsy/Ntk-ProductInfoMatch/Ntt-zline?NCNI-5&storeSelection=3304,3313,3311,3310,8560&experienceName=default']



    def parse(self, response):

        items = HomedepotSpiderItem()

        #get model
        productName = response.css('.pod-plp__description.js-podclick-analytics').css('::text').getall()

        productName = [x.strip(' ') for x in productName if len(x.strip())] 
        productName = [x.strip('\n') for x in productName if len(x.strip())] 
        productName = [x.strip('\t') for x in productName if len(x.strip())] 
        productName = [x.strip(',') for x in productName if len(x.strip())] 

        #productName = productName[0].split(',') tried to split the list into indiviudal elements


        productSKU = response.css('.pod-plp__model::text').getall()

        #get rid of all the stuff i dont need
        productSKU = [x.strip(' ') for x in productSKU] #whiteSpace
        productSKU = [x.strip('\n') for x in productSKU] 
        productSKU = [x.strip('\t') for x in productSKU] 
        productSKU = [x.strip(' Model# ') for x in productSKU] #gets rid of the model name 
        productSKU = [x.strip('\xa0') for x in productSKU] #gets rid of the model name 


        #get the price
        productPrice = response.css('.price__numbers::text').getall()

        #get rid of all the stuff i dont need
        productPrice = [x.strip(' ') for x in productPrice if len(x.strip())] 
        productPrice = [x.strip('\n') for x in productPrice if len(x.strip())] 
        productPrice = [x.strip('\t') for x in productPrice if len(x.strip())] 
        productPrice = [x.strip('$') for x in productPrice if len(x.strip())] 

        ## All prices are printing out twice, so take every other price
        productPrice = productPrice[::2]



        items['productName'] = productName
        items['productSKU'] = productSKU
        items['productPrice'] = productPrice

        yield items
```

**Items.py**

```py
import scrapy


class HomedepotSpiderItem(scrapy.Item):
     #create items
     productName = scrapy.Field()
     productSKU = scrapy.Field()
     productPrice = scrapy.Field()
     #prodcutNumRating = scrapy.Field()

     pass
```

**My Issue**

I'm doing some practice with Scrapy right now and I extracted all of this data from Home Depot's website using CSS. After extracting I manually stripped off everything all the data that I didn't need and it looked fine on the terminal. **However, after exporting everything to excel, All my extracted data is printing out into one column per row. Ex: Product Name -> all models going into one cell.** I looked into some scrapy documentation and saw that .getall() returns everything as a list so I tried splitting the list into individual elements thinking it would be fine, however that would get rid of all the data that I scraped.

Any help would be appreciated and let me know if there is any clarification that is needed!

**Edit**
I'm exporting to excel using:  scrapy crawl homeDepotCrawl -o test.csv -t csv

Comment: can you update your question with the code you use to try to export it to excel?

Comment: I have made a complete answer below which should solve your problem 100%. I think you just misunderstood how scrapy.Item works. It handles one item or one row in the spreadsheet/json at a time. Each scrapy.Item instance will output a single row when returned or yielded.

Comment: @KrisztianToth edited my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you are loading all items into one scrapy.Item instance. See code comments for more details.

Also, it is worth noting that you can use item loaders or create an item pipeline to clean the fields instead of repeating so much code. When dealing with a single item you will not need to use so much list comprehension.  Even a simple function you can call to run them through would be better than doing all this list comprehension.

[1]  https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/loaders.html

[2]  https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/item-pipeline.html

[3] https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/items.html

```
import scrapy
import re

from ..items import HomedepotSpiderItem

class HomedepotcrawlSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'homeDepotCrawl'
    allowed_domains = ['homedepot.com']
    start_urls = ['https://www.homedepot.com/b/ZLINE-Kitchen-and-Bath/N-5yc1vZhsy/Ntk-ProductInfoMatch/Ntt-zline?NCNI-5&storeSelection=3304,3313,3311,3310,8560&experienceName=default']


def parse(self, response):
    '''
    Notice when we set items variable we are not using .get or .extract yet
    We collect the top level of each item into a list of selectors. 
    Then we loop through the selectors creating a new scrapy.Item instance for each selector/item on the page. 
    The for product in items loop will step through each item selector individually.
    You can then chain .css to your variable product.css now to access each section of each 
    item individually and export them separately. 
    This will give you a new row for each item.
    '''
    items = response.css('.plp-pod')
    for product in items:
        # Create new scrapy.Item for each product in our selector list.
        item = HomedepotSpiderItem()
        item['productName'] = product.css('.pod-plp__description.js-podclickanalytics::text').get()
        # Notice we are yielding item inside of the loop.
        yield item
```

Comment: Sorry can you clarify on what you mean by chain .css

Comment: Also when trying this method the output that I'm getting looks like this

{'productName': None}
2020-02-11 13:10:56 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.homedepot.com/b/ZLINE-Kitchen-and-Bath/N-5yc1vZhsy/Ntk-ProductInfoMatch/Ntt-zline?NCNI-5&storeSelection=3304,3313,3311,3310,8560&experienceName=default>

Comment: Also would it be possible for me to use my current method of stripping off whitespace, newline chars, ect. using this method?

Comment: If you have a selector such as response.css('.item') as long as you don't use .get() you can now loop through each .item and have a new selector or you could do something like response.css('body').xpath('//span').css('div')

Comment: When I use get instead of getall, all name fields are returned as empty for your code and when I tried to modify my own

Comment: Its not exact code to solve your problem but the principle that you can select each item and loop through them individually and grab each description one at a time. Load it into a scrapy item and yield the item one at a time. I didn't test the code just explained why you are having problems and demonstrated how one should use scrapy items.

Comment: I fixed up my program with your solution, so I'll mark your answer as the solution and edit it with the exact solution. Thanks!!

Comment: sorry an extra question, I've noticed that scrapy appends each output to the .csv file, is there any way to overwrite all the data that was outputted? I looked into it and saw that normally the only way is to delete the file and just make it again.

Comment: Yeah to my knowledge it will always append at the end of the file

Comment: why is there a bounty on this question with an accepted answer? I'm confused.

Comment: sorry i thought it would automatically give the bounty to an accepted answer, I think you got the +50 now that I awarded it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207798/discussion-between-chrishg-and-thepyguy).

Comment: how did you get .plp-pod