# Problem while extracting prices from booking.com with scrapy css

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm trying to extract hotel names alongside their prices from the booking.com website. I managed to extract the hotel names and store them in item containers, however I'm struggling to extract the belonging prices from the webpage.
My code is below:

```
import scrapy

from ..items import KonkurrenzanalyseItem


class Konkurrenzanalyse(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'Booking'
    start_urls = [
    'https://www.booking.com/searchresults.de.html?aid=304142&label=gen173nr-1DCAEoggI46AdIM1gEaDuIAQGYAQe4AQfIAQ3YAQPoAQGIAgGoAgO4AuadkPIFwAIB&sid=f5f5396810ee33128397135370be94ba&tmpl=searchresults&checkin_month=2&checkin_monthday=18&checkin_year=2020&checkout_month=2&checkout_monthday=19&checkout_year=2020&class_interval=1&dest_id=-1821233&dest_type=city&dtdisc=0&from_sf=1&group_adults=2&group_children=0&inac=0&index_postcard=0&label_click=undef&no_rooms=1&order=price&postcard=0&raw_dest_type=city&room1=A%2CA&sb_price_type=total&shw_aparth=1&slp_r_match=0&src_elem=sb&srpvid=704b677afe570188&ss=Lübeck&ss_all=0&ssb=empty&sshis=0&ssne=Lübeck&ssne_untouched=Lübeck&top_ufis=1&rows=25&offset=25'
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        items = KonkurrenzanalyseItem()

        hotel_name = response.css('.sr-hotel__name::text').extract()
        hotel_price = response.css('.bui-price-display__value::text').extract()

        items['hotel_name'] = hotel_name
        items['hotel_price'] = hotel_price

        yield items
```

The next image represents the price that I want to extract from the html code:
[image]

By now, the code outputs the following values in which the prices are not being listed yet:
[image]

Since I am quite a newbie in this environment, please excuse me if my question is not 100% accurately formulated.

Comment: Don't post images of text. (Sent from my iPhone, that's one good reason.)

Comment: see my answer to this recent question to solve your problem.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60122716/scrapy-using-css-to-extract-data-and-excel-export-everything-into-one-cell/60130852#60130852

Comment: I have checked your recent answer on a similar problem. My take away is, that I should loop and yield each item individually in order to obtain the desired output for the price. However, even if I do so I still have the problem of not receiving any value for the prices and I still don't know why.

Comment: use scrapy shell and fetch the URL and see if the data is actually there. if it is showing in the browser but not in scrapy it may be loaded in via JS. use the browser inspector tool in the network tab to see if there is an XHR request that loads in the prices.

Comment: Thank you very much!
I checked the url with scrapy shell -> view(response) and the hotel names were still in place but the prices were missing because when converting the url into scrapy the dates are not adopted -which is mandatory to obtain the room prices.
Do you have an idea how that issue could be solved?

Answer (score 1):

Seems to me like your css selector is just a little bit off, try:

```
hotel_price = response.css('div.bui-price-display__value.prco-inline-block-maker-helper::text').extract_first()
```

Have a look at this helpful css slector resource [here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp)